# What is difference in memory address and Java HashCode

Tags: java, string, memory-address

```
Even if you have two different strings with the same value, they will have the same hashcode.

In the below example HashCode is the same? But the memory address is the same? How I can get it in java.
```

> jshell> var a = new String("Ranga")
>
> a ==> "Ranga"
>
> jshell> var b = new String("Ranga")
>
> b ==> "Ranga"
>
> jshell> a.hashCode()
>
> $31 ==> 78727449
>
> jshell> b.hashCode()
>
> $32 ==> 78727449
>
> jshell> a == b
>
> $33 ==> false

Comment: Why? What is the problem you are trying to solve or thing you are trying to do? Thinking about memory address in Java means you're already on the wrong track...

Comment: You cannot access memory locations in java. Even if you could, what would be the use of it? You cannot work with it.

Comment: The question that you should ask yourself is, "does Java has pointers like C/C++?" and then you will be able to answer this question yourself.

Comment: hashCode() != memory location. In the current implementation of hotspot, the identityHashCode does not depend on the memory location.

Comment: if you can add some refer links that will be helpful @JohannesKuhn

Comment: @Deadpool https://srvaroa.github.io/jvm/java/openjdk/biased-locking/2017/01/30/hashCode.html

Comment: https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/49708/can-we-print-address-of-an-object-in-java-if-yes-then-how-is-it-possible

Comment: @AjaySharma the most "useful" thing in this "discussion" is that Unsafe might have something. After looking through the methods of Unsafe, I could not find anything that would return an address for an object (which might change btw).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the original hashCode for the String before it was altered you can do this:

```java
String foo = ...some string
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(foo));
```

According to the documenation for the `hashCode`

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java™ programming language.)